# Possible to get a stack trace to see what 'led up to' a particular breakpoint?

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, debugging, breakpoints, stack-trace

A bit more context:

I have a method that is called, and the breakpoint is placed at the start of this method.

Once the debugger hits this - how can I tell what other part of the code invoked the method? (i.e. right before it hit this breakpoint)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In the Debug menu, there is a "Windows" sub menu.  Select "Call Stack" within this and you will have your stack trace.  You can even interactively click each line to see the method invocation in the appropriate source file as you "walk" up the stack.

Note: This option only shows up *whilst* debugging.

Comment: Perfect. Thanks a lot. (Will accept as answer when it allows me to). Response to edit: That's what I was after anyway; if I weren't debugging I'd just find all references. Thanks again.